# Confluent-Kafka python delete_topic getting recreated

Tags: python, apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-python

When I'm trying to **delete a Kafka topic using Confluent-Kafka AdminClient Delete_topic**, The topic is getting deleted for the moment but is getting recreated after few seconds.

I tried **Producer.flush() , Consumer.unsubscribe()** to avoid recreating but still unable to figure out why it is getting recreated.

However, when i try to manually delete same topic after whole process completion using an individual python script it is getting deleted.

Comment: Set `auto.create.topics.enable=false` in Kafka config to disable this behaviour.

Comment: Yeah that can be done but same Kafka environment is being used by other processes so we are not sure if they are always creating topic before using or if it is created with produce(). Is there any other work around?